# Export array of object to csv file in js with desin

Tags: javascript, csv, export, export-to-csv

I'v been tried to export array of object to csv file, and that's fine for me.
But my problem is to coloring the cells of data in csv file before exporting, is this action possible in my case?

Comment: CSV does not support colors. You're thinking of xlsx.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your help

Comment: I need to make a separator between data blocks, i mean i hava data in order by id, so I want to separate between them. Example:          id, title,...                                                                     1 blabla....                                                              Separator.                                                                2 xyz...  etc